# Android activity not found error?

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm getting an activity not found exception. I'm starting a **SplashScreen** Activity and then passing the control to the **MainActivity**.

Here is my manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="se.copernicus.activity"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="5" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".SplashScreenActivity" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="se.copernicus.activity.MainActivity" >
     </activity>

        <activity
            android:label="@string/second_activity"
            android:name="se.copernicus.activity.Secondactivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

This is the splash screen activity that I am starting at first.

```
public class SplashScreenActivity extends Activity {
protected boolean _active = true;
protected int _splashTime = 5000;
Intent intent = new Intent("se.copernicus.activity.MainActivity");
Thread splashTread = null;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    splashTread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                int waited = 0;
                Log.i("Coming here 1","Coming here 1");
                while(_active && (waited < _splashTime)) {
                    sleep(50);
                    Log.i("Coming here 2","Coming here 2");
                    if(_active) {
                        waited += 50;
                        Log.i("Coming here 3","Coming here 3");
                    }
                }
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                // do nothing
            }  finally {
                finish();
                Log.i("Coming here 4","Coming here 4");
                startActivity(intent);

                Log.i("Coming here 5","Coming here 5");

                if(splashTread!= null){
                    splashTread.stop();
                    splashTread=null;
                }
            }
        }
    };
    splashTread.start();
}
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        _active = false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

I've declared the activity in the manifest double checked for errors, the package name too. And yet this error shows up. Where am I making a mistake ?

**The error logs:**

```
E/AndroidRuntime(340): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=se.copernicus.activity.MainActivity }
E/AndroidRuntime(340):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1408)
E/AndroidRuntime(340):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1378)
E/AndroidRuntime(340):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2827)
E/AndroidRuntime(340):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2933)
E/AndroidRuntime(340):  at se.copernicus.activity.SplashScreenActivity$1.run(SplashScreenActivity.java:41)
```

Comment: Plz provide your error logs ...

Comment: @Vinoth: and also full manifest file.

Comment: Hi kool4u, Adil Soomro. I've just added the error log

Comment: Clean and build the project and then try running the project again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [`Intent(String)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#Intent%28java.lang.String%29) documentation:

> `public Intent (String action)`
>
> `action` The Intent action, such as ACTION_VIEW.

---

Now take a look at this piece of your code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("se.copernicus.activity.MainActivity");
```

It says that you want to start activity with action `"se.copernicus.activity.MainActivity"`. But you don't want that. You want to start activity of class `se.copernicus.activity.MainActivity`. These are two different things!

---

And now look at error message:

```
No Activity found to handle Intent { act=se.copernicus.activity.MainActivity }
```

Notice the `act` part in error message, it stands for `Action`. This means that Android can not resolve any activity for action `"se.copernicus.activity.MainActivity"`. This only proves my previous point.

---

Instead of treating your class name as action, you need to create correct `Intent` with empty action value, but with correct `Activity` class name (more precisely with correct Component Id). So you actually need to create `Intent` using another `Intent` constructor:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
```

Comment: wonderful explanation...
Made me understand the Intent better.
Thanks inazaruk !!

Comment: I didn't understand what the "act" meant in the error.. thanks for clearing that up !!

Answer (score 1):

Just finish() your activity after launching ur activity ...

```
finally {

            Log.i("Coming here 4","Coming here 4");
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
          ......
```

}

Answer (score 0):

either set packagename in menifest application tag or give fully qualified activity name in SplashScreen activity

Answer (score 0):

Uh. Try to do it like this.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
 startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I tried that Sver, it didn't work either. I was getting an error.